# Apache to serve both static file and webapp

Tags: apache-2.4, centos7, virtualhost, httpd

I have apache running on below reverse proxy config to serve java webapp content

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
SSLProxyEngine on
ProxyPreserveHost On
ProxyRequests Off

ServerName www.example.com
ServerAlias example.com

<Location />
        Order deny,allow
        Allow from all
        SetOutputFilter INFLATE;DEFLATE

        ProxyPass  http://localhost:7070/
        ProxyPassReverse  http://localhost:7070/
        AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html text/plain text/xml text/css text/javascript application/javascript
</Location>

</VirtualHost>
```

Now i want to add static file folder and should be served under the same same domain name but under "/auth" path
https://example.com/auth

so i added below config just below the above

```
<Location /auth>
      Require all granted
      Allow from all
</Location>

Alias "/auth" "/var/www/html/auth"
DocumentRoot /var/www/html/auth/
<Directory /var/www/html/auth>
        Require all granted
        DirectoryIndex index.html
</Directory>
```

But when i try "https://example.com/auth" it still goes to java webapp and gives me 404.
But when i curl localhost i can see webpage content

```
curl http://localhost
```

how to access static content on /var/www/html/auth/ using  https://example.com/auth URL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to explicitly remove that location from the proxy by using the `ProxyPass "!"` directive. This should be done in the `Location` what you don't need to be proxyed, and this block should be written *after* the proxy block, like this:

```
<Location />
  ProxyPass http://localhost:7070/
  (...)
</Location>

<Location /auth>
  ProxyPass "!"
</Location>
```

Comment: Thanks mate. This worked like a charm